# REST API на Spring MVC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Это моя первая попытка создания веб приложения, просьба подсказать, как решить ошибку, которую получаю при деплое? Вот стектрейс и др.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPlayerService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPlayerDAO' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.game.model.Player
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPlayerDAO' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.game.model.Player
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.game.model.Player
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.game.model.Player
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85)
```

PlayerController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/players")
public class PlayerController {

    private PlayerService playerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPlayerService(PlayerService playerService) {
        this.playerService = playerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Player> getPlayer(@PathVariable("id") Long playerId) {
        .........................
    }
```

PlayerServiceImpl

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService{

    private PlayerDAO playerDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setPlayerDAO(PlayerDAO playerDAO) {
        this.playerDAO=playerDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public Player getById(Long id) {
        log.info("IN PlayerServiceImpl getById{}", id);
        return playerDAO.findById(id).get();
    }
```

PlayerDAO

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerDAO extends JpaRepository <Player, Long> {

}
```

Player

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
```

BaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.game")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/index");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.getObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        converter.getObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.game")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.game.repository")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.game.entity");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Profile("prod")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rpg?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("4747");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSourceForTests() {

        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScript("test.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы сущности ищите в `em.setPackagesToScan("com.game.entity");`, а у вас сущность расположена в `com.game.model.Player`.

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало